# Draw a Rectangle Using Mouse Click

Tags: java, swing

I'm having issues getting a rectangle drawn when the mouse is clicked on screen in my JFrame. I've tried a few different methods and the closest I've gotten is just getting the coordinates appearing. Any drawing seems to be ignored for some reason.

```
package pathfinder;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

public class forLoopDesign extends JPanel{

//offsets for hard-coded path
int hOffset = 40;
int vOffset = 40;

//check if adjacent block is wall
boolean wall = false;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    draw(g);
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
   //draw start and end points
    g.setColor(Color.magenta);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawString("Start", 7, 24);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(720, 720, 40, 40);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawString("Finish", 724, 744);

   //draw grid
    g.setColor(Color.black);       
    for(int i=0; i<760; i+=40){
        for(int j=0; j<800; j+= 40){
            g.drawRect(i, j, 40, 40);
        }
    }

   //draw hard-coded path
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    for(int i=0; i< 17; i++){
        g.fillRect(hOffset + 1, vOffset + 1, 39, 39);
        hOffset += 40;
        vOffset += 40;
    }

   //check for mouse click, print coordinates
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            System.out.println("(x, y) of mouse click= (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
            g.fillRect(200,200,40,40);
        }
    });
}

//draw wall at mouse click location
public void highlightSquare(int x, int y, Graphics g){
    wall = true;
    System.out.println("wall value=" + wall);

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 40, 40);
}

//initialize jframe properties
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().add(new forLoopDesign(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(767, 790);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}}
```

My end goal is to be able to draw rectangles on the screen to create a maze like screen and have the program navigate its way through it (cyan squares). This is an ambitious project and I realize I've probably made many mistakes so far so feel free to add any other criticisms you might have. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

All custom painting needs to be done in the `paintComponent(..)` method.

So in your `mouseClick` logic you need to save the point where you clicked in an `ArrayList` and invoke `repaint()`. Then the `paintComponent(...)` method needs to iterate through the `ArrayList` to paint the rectangle at the given point.

See the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example of this approach.

Comment: Could you give an example? Calling 'repaint()' in my code clears what I have right now rather than drawing out the new shape. I'd like to keep what's on the screen and add the new shapes on top. Sorry if I'm being difficult, still figuring java out

Comment: Read the last line of your comment, apologies

Comment: `Calling 'repaint()' in my code clears what I have right now rather than drawing out the new shape` - yes, whenever a component is painted the first step is to clear the background and then repaint everything again, which is why you need to iterate through the ArrayList to repaint every again.

Comment: @Tylerxc, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.